# Como usar o Selenium WebDriver findElement(By.xpath())?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Olá, por favor, estou tentando pegar informações em um site público: nome de uma votação, data e tabela com lista de votos

Esse site: http://www2.camara.leg.br/atividade-legislativa/plenario/chamadaExterna.html?link=http://www.camara.gov.br/internet/votacao/mostraVotacao.asp?ideVotacao=6706&tipo=partido

Usei Python 3, selenium webdriver e PhantomJS:

```
from selenium import webdriver

path_to_phantomjs = '/Users/George/Documents/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs'

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = path_to_phantomjs)

browser.get("http://www2.camara.leg.br/atividade-legislativa/plenario/chamadaExterna.html?link=http://www.camara.gov.br/internet/votacao/mostraVotacao.asp?ideVotacao=6706&tipo=partido")

nome_votacao = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='corpoVotacao']/p[3]/text()")

data_votacao = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='corpoVotacao']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p[1]/text()[1]")

list_deputados = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//table[@class='tabela-2']")
```

Mas parece que estou selecionando de forma errada os locais

O nome_votacao aparece essa mensagem de erro:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidSelectorException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e67933637ae0> in <module>()
----> 1 nome_votacao = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='corpoVotacao']/p[3]/text()")

c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\code\votos\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    363             driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
    364         """
--> 365         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    366 
    367     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):

c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\code\votos\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    841         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    842             'using': by,
--> 843             'value': value})['value']
    844 
    845     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\code\votos\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    306         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    307         if response:
--> 308             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    309             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    310                 response.get('value', None))

c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\code\votos\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    192         elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException and 'alert' in value:
    193             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].get('text'))
--> 194         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    195 
    196     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

InvalidSelectorException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[@id='corpoVotacao']/p[3]/text() because of the following error:\nError: INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 51","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"118","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:55799","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"value\": \"//[@id='corpoVotacao']/p[3]/text()\", \"sessionId\": \"366665f0-be24-11e7-aa25-75da268b98e2\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/366665f0-be24-11e7-aa25-75da268b98e2/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

O data_votacao essa mensagem de erro:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidSelectorException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-24c43341f310> in <module>()
----> 1 data_votacao = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='corpoVotacao']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p[1]/text()[1]")

c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\code\votos\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    363             driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
    364         """
--> 365         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    366 
    367     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):

c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\code\votos\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    841         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    842             'using': by,
--> 843             'value': value})['value']
    844 
    845     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\code\votos\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    306         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    307         if response:
--> 308             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    309             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    310                 response.get('value', None))

c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\code\votos\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    192         elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException and 'alert' in value:
    193             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].get('text'))
--> 194         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    195 
    196     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

InvalidSelectorException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[@id='corpoVotacao']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p[1]/text()[1] because of the following error:\nError: INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 51","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"143","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:55799","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"value\": \"//[@id='corpoVotacao']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p[1]/text()[1]\", \"sessionId\": \"366665f0-be24-11e7-aa25-75da268b98e2\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/366665f0-be24-11e7-aa25-75da268b98e2/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

E o list_deputados gera uma lista vazia

O data_votacao era para ter esse conteúdo: "10/11/2015 20:15". E tem esse XPath no inspect: //*[@id="corpoVotacao"]/p[2]/text()[1]

O nome_votação era para ter esse conteúdo: "MPV Nº 688/2015 - PROJETO DE LEI DE CONVERSÃO - Nominal Eletrônica". E tem esse XPath no inspect: //*[@id="corpoVotacao"]/p[3]/text()

E o list_deputados a tabela completa com os votos (nomes, UF e voto) a partir da linha Parlamentar. Tem esse XPath: //*[@id="listagem"]/table. E o class="tabela-2"

Alguém sabe a forma correta dos comandos? Ou algum tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço de python, mas em java tu localiza o elemento pelo findElement e depois tu "pega" o texto.

```
String texto = "Driver".findElement("xpath").getText();
```

Ou seja, depois de localizar, vc getText() do elemento
Deve ter um equivalente em python

Answer (score 0):

Reinaldo,

Você está tentando manipular dados do tipo iframe que não podem ser diretamente acessados pelo metodo findelement.

Veja o site https://dzone.com/articles/modern-python-web-scraping-using-multiple-librarie